# R Network - Color-code the nodes based on a separate vector

Tags: r

I have a matrix `B` and a vector `A` (the matrix has value 0 or 1; the vector has value from 0 to 1 continuously; `a,b,c` are 3 attributes):

```
B = matrix(c(0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0),nrow=3,ncol=3)
rownames(B)<-c("a", "b", "c")

A = c(0.23,0.56,0.78)
```

I tried to create a network, with the nodes **gradient colored** based on the value in vector A (let's say the scale is from white to black, than the attribute `c` with value 0.78 is darker than `a` with value 0.23). I tried these lines but they fail to color-code the nodes.

```
require(Rgraphviz)
am.graph<-new("graphAM", adjMat=B, edgemode="directed")
plot(am.graph, attrs = list(node = list(fillcolor = A),
                        edge = list(arrowsize=0.5)))
```

Really appreciate any help. I am new to R so really sorry if my explanation is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use package igraph:

```
library(igraph)
B = matrix(c(0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0),nrow=3,ncol=3)
rownames(B)<-c("a", "b", "c")
A = c(0.23,0.56,0.78)*100
g<- graph.adjacency(B)

fine = 500 # this will adjust the resolving power.
palette = colorRampPalette(c('green','darkgreen'))
#this gives you the colors you want for every point
graphCol = palette(fine)[as.numeric(cut(A,breaks = fine))]
plot(g, vertex.size=A, vertex.color = graphCol)
```

If you don't want vertexes of different sizes, just omit 'vertex.size=A' in your plot!

Comment: Thanks Ale. Sorry I was not clear on my question. I would like gradient colors, not just 3 different colors since the real vector in my data set has a lot of values. Any suggestions?